# String Date Format Issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have imported a csv using Imprt Flat file option. The file contains string columns which got converted into nvarchar(50) datatype.
The csv contains date values.
I need to load this data containing the date columns (in format 12/16/2020 19:09:58) to 2020-12-16 19:09:58.000 .
I tried using the below way using convert.

```
select convert(datetime, delta_val, 101) from dbo.my_table;
```

But getting the below error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue? have tried using cast and format methods as well. Same issue persists.

Comment: `select convert(datetime, '12/16/2020 19:09:58', 101)` has no issues, so I suggest you also have different formats (or altogether non-date values). You can find them using `TRY_CONVERT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by HoneyBadger, used try_convert. Working now.

```
select try_convert(datetime, delta_val) from dbo.my_table;
```

Comment: Don't forget that `TRY_CONVERT` returns `NULL` for data that cannot be converted, so you'll loose data.

Comment: ohh.. then need to check on that issue then as well.

Comment: Exactly, you can use `WHERE try_convert(datetime, delta_val) IS NULL AND delta_val IS NOT NULL`